# Arduino remote-controlled car stops after a few seconds

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

I am making a remotely controlled car for a project at Uni. The car is made from an Arduino Uno, a 2 motor driver and a Bluetooth transceiver. I have written some code for it, but it randomly stops after 2 or 3 loops.

Here is my code:

```c++
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"

typedef unsigned char u8;

typedef struct {
  u8 right;
  u8 left;
} speed;

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(4, 2);

const u8 RIGHT_MOTOR_PIN1 = 3;
const u8 RIGHT_MOTOR_PIN2 = 5;
const u8 LEFT_MOTOR_PIN1 = 6;
const u8 LEFT_MOTOR_PIN2 = 9;

const u8 MAX_SPEED = 0xFFU;
const u8 HALF_SPEED = MAX_SPEED / 2;
const u8 NO_SPEED = 0x0U;

static u8 command = 0U;
static speed potentialSpeed;
static speed actualSpeed;

void setup() {
  bluetooth.begin(115200);
  while (0U != bluetooth.available()) bluetooth.read();
  potentialSpeed.right = MAX_SPEED;
  potentialSpeed.left = MAX_SPEED;
  actualSpeed.right = NO_SPEED;
  actualSpeed.left = NO_SPEED;
}

void loop() {
  readCommand();
  {
    if (clockwise(command)) {
      if (0U == (command & 0xFEU)) {
        actualSpeed.right = - MAX_SPEED;
        actualSpeed.left = + MAX_SPEED;
      }
    } else if (counterclockwise(command)) {
      if (0U == (command & 0xFDU)) {
        actualSpeed.right = + MAX_SPEED;
        actualSpeed.left = - MAX_SPEED;
      }
    } else {
      if (right(command)) {
        potentialSpeed.right = HALF_SPEED;
      }
      if (left(command)) {
        potentialSpeed.left = HALF_SPEED;
      }
      if (forward(command)) {
        if (!backward(command)) {
          actualSpeed.right = + potentialSpeed.right;
          actualSpeed.left = + potentialSpeed.left;
        }
      } else if (backward(command)) {
        actualSpeed.right = - potentialSpeed.right;
        actualSpeed.left = - potentialSpeed.left;
      }
    }
    if (0U == command) {
      potentialSpeed.right = MAX_SPEED;
      potentialSpeed.left = MAX_SPEED;
      actualSpeed.right = NO_SPEED;
      actualSpeed.left = NO_SPEED;
    }
  }
  runAt(actualSpeed);
  delay(95);
}

void readCommand(void) {
  command = 0U;
  if (1U == bluetooth.available())
    command = bluetooth.read();
}

inline boolean clockwise(u8 command) {
  return (boolean)((command >> 0U) & 1U);
}
inline boolean counterclockwise(u8 command) {
  return (boolean)((command >> 1U) & 1U);
}
inline boolean right(u8 command) {
  return (boolean)((command >> 2U) & 1U);
}
inline boolean left(u8 command) {
  return (boolean)((command >> 3U) & 1U);
}
inline boolean forward(u8 command) {
  return (boolean)((command >> 4U) & 1U);
}
inline boolean backward(u8 command) {
  return (boolean)((command >> 5U) & 1U);
}

void runAt(speed Speed) {
  if (Speed.right > 0U) {
    analogWrite(RIGHT_MOTOR_PIN1, 0U);
    analogWrite(RIGHT_MOTOR_PIN2, Speed.right);
  } else {
    analogWrite(RIGHT_MOTOR_PIN1, (-(Speed.right)));
    analogWrite(RIGHT_MOTOR_PIN2, 0U);
  }
  if (Speed.left > 0U) {
    analogWrite(LEFT_MOTOR_PIN1, 0U);
    analogWrite(LEFT_MOTOR_PIN2, Speed.left);
  }
  else {
    analogWrite(LEFT_MOTOR_PIN1, (-(Speed.left)));
    analogWrite(LEFT_MOTOR_PIN2, 0U);
  }
}
```

Could you please help me find the cause?
Also, I am unable to make it go backwards. Can that be related?

Comment: replace  `if (1U == bluetooth.available()) command = bluetooth.read();` with a fixed command `command = turn_left` .... see if it keeps doing it

Comment: SoftwareSerial speed is limited. use 9600 or 19200 baud

Comment: have you tried to debug the serial communication of what kind of command you are getting from the Bluetooth module? you might get a wrong baud or the software is not sending correct data

Comment: I have the same problem. Here is my code: #include <Servo.h> #include <AFMotor.h> #include <SoftwareSerial.h> // TX RX software library for bluetooth Servo myservo; // create servo object to control a servo // a maximum of eight servo objects can be created AF_DCMotor motor1(1, MOTOR12_1KHZ ); //create motor #1 using M1 output on Motor Drive Shield, set to 1kHz PWM frequency int state = '0'; int PosRight = 45; int PosLeft = 135; int PosF = 90; int pos = 90; int Speed = 150; void setup() { Serial.begin(9600); myservo.attach(9); // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object } void loop() {

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the bluetooth module would receive bytes faster than the SoftwareSerial was able to read, so `bluetooth.available()` would return more than `1U` after a couple of loops. This was fixed by changing the following:

```
void readCommand(void) {
  command = 0U;
  if (bluetooth.available()) {
    while(bluetooth.available() > 1U)
      bluetooth.read();
    command = bluetooth.read();
  }
}
```

The 'make-it-run-backwards' problem was also solved, but was unrelated.